# Remove unwanted elements when converting JSON to CSV

Tags: javascript, json, angular, csv, typescript

I have a set of JSON data like this:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Sam","birthday":"12December","age":"15"},
{"id":2,"name":"Ash","birthday":"12January","age":"23"}
```

I passed the data through the function:

```
ConvertToCSV(data)
```

Now I am able to get id, name, birthday and age in the csv. However, I want to remove birthday column during the conversion so that it does not show up in the csv generated. How can I do that?

Current Output:

```
id | name | birthday   | age      
1  | Sam  | 12December | 15      
2  | Ash  | 12January  | 23
```

Desired Output:

```
id | name | age
1  | Sam  | 15
2  | Ash  | 23
```

Here is the original code:

```
ConvertToCSV(data) {
        var array = $.parseJSON('[' + data + ']');
        var fields = Object.keys(array[0]);
        var replacer = function(key, value) { return value === null ? '' : value } 
        var csv = array.map(function(row){
            return fields.map(function(fieldname){
                return JSON.stringify(row[fieldname], replacer)
            }).join(',')
        })
        csv.unshift(fields.join(',')) // add header column
        var str = csv.join('\r\n');
        return str;
    }
```

I added the following into the function according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top):

```
for(var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var index = array[i].birthday;
    array[i].splice(index, 1);
}
```

But the above code does not work, anyone can help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the fields to remove 'birthday':

```
var fields = Object.keys(array[0])
  .filter(field => field !== 'birthday');
```

Full code (using native JSON.parse):

```js
var data = `
{"id":1,"name":"Sam","birthday":"12December","age":"15"},
{"id":2,"name":"Ash","birthday":"12January","age":"23"}
`;

var ConvertToCSV = (data) => {
    var array = JSON.parse('[' + data + ']');
    var fields = Object.keys(array[0]).filter(field => field !== 'birthday');
    var replacer = function (key, value) { return value === null ? '' : value }
    var csv = array.map(function (row) {
        return fields.map(function (fieldname) {
            return JSON.stringify(row[fieldname], replacer)
        }).join(',')
    })
    csv.unshift(fields.join(',')) // add header column
    var str = csv.join('\r\n');
    return str;
};

console.log(ConvertToCSV(data));
```

Comment: var fields = Object.keys(array[0]).filter(field => field !== 'birthday' && field !== 'age');